# Wonky Page Displayed on Console and Blank S3 Page

Tags: browser, display

Newbie here--please be patient. I have searched for answers here and on other sites.  I'ma total newbie without the technical know-how that you all have, so I am struggling. When I login to my management console, I have broken image icons and it looks pretty bare bones.  When I go to the S3 page, I see only a header and footer.  The time zone is set on Global and when I click on the down arrow, all the time zones are grayed out.  I have tried both Chrome and MSEdge--same result. I've cleared the cache but that didn't solve the problem. I logged into my iPad and could see everything but working from that is less than ideal. Can anyone help?[aws S3 buckets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGfiR.png)

Restarted laptop
Refreshed pages multiple times
Switched from Chrome browser to MSEdge
Cleared cache hoping that would solve the problem but no luck.